# Not getting exact text from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parser

I am trying to get the exact text from the HTML page but output text is different than expected text.

> text on HTML page

```
Салнас 14
```

> text show by beautifulSoup

```
ĐĄĐ°ĐťĐ˝Đ°Ń 14
```

My code is

```
page = BeautifulSoup(url.read(),'html.parser')
page.find(id='tdo_11').text
```

> Html inspect code for the div

```
<td class="ads_opt" id="tdo_11" nowrap=""><b>Салнас 14</b></td>
```

I'm not understanding what causes this?
Should I use the different parser?

Comment: Have you tried changing the text encoding?

Comment: You need to find out what character encoding the page is using, e.g. UTF8.

Comment: It looks like an encoding problem to me. Have you tried to encode the text using the character encoding the page uses?

Comment: Can you give us the URL of the page?

Comment: @AlexHall https://www.ss.lv/msg/ru/real-estate/flats/riga/plyavnieki/onlol.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `requests` library for making HTTP requests, it's much better than what Python has built in for many reasons. It takes care of encodings automatically and intelligently.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.ss.lv/msg/ru/real-estate/flats/riga/plyavnieki/onlol.html')
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```